# Add error box for text field on keypress function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to restrict text boxes with character and numbers.
When I try to enter number in `project name` field it should add `error box` for that field.Similarly,When I start entering valid project name `error box` should be hide.
But its not working.Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.onlyAlphabets').keypress(function (e) {
        debugger
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            $(this).removeClass('error')
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('error')
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.onlyNumeric').keypress(function (event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false
        }
        else {         
            return true;
        }
  
});
});
```

```css
.error{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Project Name<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control onlyAlphabets projectName required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Client Name<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="client" class="form-control onlyAlphabets clientName required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">On site Co-ordinator<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="onsite_coordinator" class="form-control onlyAlphabets onsiteCoOrd required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Duration(In months)<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="duration" class="form-control onlyNumeric duration required"></label>
                </div>
```

Comment: In Your code The numeric value is not accepted then why U need to remove it

Comment: Sorry check now

Comment: It's working fine for me. As-Is !

Comment: What I see so far is all your text boxes with class onlyAlphabets only accepts alpha keys and shows a red validation error box if you try to input nun-alpha value. The last text box only accepts numbers and doesn't show that validation error box which is again as per to your code looks intended because it doesn't have $(this).addClass('error') or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding **Error Box** Just You restrict the numbers in that fields.
Because You write the function within `Keypress` event. So Until You press valid character it will show the Error

So Just simply restrict the numbers in those fields like You did for Duration

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.onlyAlphabets').keypress(function (e) {
        debugger
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            
            return true;
        }
        else {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.onlyNumeric').keypress(function (event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false
        }
        else {         
            return true;
        }
  
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Project Name <span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control onlyAlphabets projectName required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Client Name<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="client" class="form-control onlyAlphabets clientName required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">On site Co-ordinator<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="onsite_coordinator" class="form-control onlyAlphabets onsiteCoOrd required"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 txtBoxMargin">
                    <label class="displayBlock">Duration(In months)<span class="reqField">*</span></label>
                    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin"><input type="text" name="duration" class="form-control onlyNumeric duration required"></label>
                </div>
```